# GitHub: Is it possible to watch a specific branch instead of the entire repo?

Tags: github

My users are asking for this, but I do not see it as a supported feature yet. Many only want to be notified when a push to a specific release branch occurs, for example. They do not want to receive notifications for every push to every branch in a watched repo. Is there a way to achieve this level of granularity, or is it stuck at "all or nothing"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may be possible using webhooks. A server could be created that rescieves the Webhook and notifies the users that want to if the action is performed on the release branch.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking along those same lines as well originally, but one complication would be - the webhook would need to be modifiable so users could select the branches and repos they are interested in seeing notifications from. It wouldn't be a static list.  A separate web interface could accomplish that, but ... someone then has to write a web interface in addition to a webhook, and now users have to go _somewhere else_ just to enable GitHub push emails :-)